# ¿Cómo sumar un ciclo for?

Tags: r, bucle-for

actualmente estoy intentando probar ciertas propiedad en estadistica, y para una de ellas debo comprobar si la sumatoria de ciertos numeros multiplicados por una probabilidad dada es igual a su media. (Sum(x)*prob(x)=mean(x))
Para ello se me ocurrio usar un ejemplo sencillo, usando las posibilidades de un dado.

Asi que mi idea era hacer un ciclo "for" para hacer una suma acumulada, pero no sé cómo guardar cada output del ciclo en una lista por ejemplo, para despues sumarla:

```
for (x in 1:6){
  prob=1/6
  c <- c(prob*x)
}
```

(1*1/6 + 2*1/6 + ... + 6*1/6)

Use ese comando pensando que guardaria cada output y crearia una lista, pero creo que solo guarda el resultado mostrado al final porque se actualiza constantemente. Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer para guardar cada resultado de mi ciclo for?

Se que tambien puedo hacer el analisis de la siguiente forma:

```
x <- c(1:6)
prob <- c(1/6)
c <- data.frame(x, prob)
c <- mutate(c, x*prob)
sum(c$`x * prob`)
```

Pero me preguntaba si se puede con un ciclo for para mas eficiencia.
Igual si se les ocurre una forma mas eficiente de realizar esta accion por favor compartanla :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer una suma acumulada mediante un ciclo `for` el patrón más simple es acumular en una variable inicializada fuera del ciclo y en un lista guardar cada valor acumulado:

```
suma_acumulada <- 0
valores <- list()
prob <- 1/6
for (x in 1:6){
  suma_acumulada <- suma_acumulada + (prob*x)
  valores[[x]] <- suma_acumulada
}
suma_acumulada
unlist(valores)

[1] 3.5
[1] 0.1666667 0.5000000 1.0000000 1.6666667 2.5000000 3.5000000
```

Sin embargo, en R ya tienes funciones vectorizadas que suelen ser más óptimas que un ciclo `for` estándar:

```
cumsum(prob * 1:6)
[1] 0.1666667 0.5000000 1.0000000 1.6666667 2.5000000 3.5000000
```

Fuera de tu pregunta, te recomiendo que no uses nombres reservados como variables, en tu ejemplo `c()` es una función central de R, evita usar ese nombre para bautizar cualquier variable.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias. Solo una pregunta, porque se usaron llaves dobles en "valores[[x]]", hay alguna diferencia en usar llaves simples "valores[x]?

Comment: La casualidad que acabo de responder otra pregunta dónde justamente respondo esto, fijate a ver si te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/554647/31764