# Añadir un valor a un elemento de una lista

Tags: r

Poseo la siguiente lista:
`mi.lista <- list(a = 1:3, b = c("hola", "adiós"))`

Estoy buscando la manera de agregarle al segundo elemento `[["b"]]` el valor `"hasta luego"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando trabajas con listas, R tiene una particularidad que lo hace distinto a cualquier otro lenguaje, para referenciar un elemento de una lista tienes la opción clásica `mi.lista[2]` la cual te retorna una nueva lista con un único elemento (el segundo) pero no el elemento en sí, cuando necesites realmente manipular un elemento en particular, debes usar los corchetes dobles `[[`, para demostrarlo:

```
> class(mi.lista[2])
[1] "list"
> class(mi.lista[[2]])
[1] "character"
```

Vemos que los corchetes simples, no retornan una lista y los dobles el vector guardado en el segundo elemento.

Ahora, volviendo a tu pregunta, lo que buscas puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
mi.lista[[2]] <- c(mi.lista[[2]], 'hasta luego')
```

o bien

```
mi.lista[[2]] <- append(mi.lista[[2]], 'hasta luego')
```

o mediante el nombre del elemento:

```
mi.lista$b <- c(mi.lista$b, 'hasta luego')
```

Comment: La siguiente manera de realizar la consulta `mi.lista[[2]] <- c(mi.lista[[2]], 'hasta luego')` me pareció la mas sencilla por como vengo entendiendo. Muchas gracias!